# Algorithm for holonomic sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, d-modules

A sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of complex numbers is called *polynomially recursive* (*P-recursive*) or *holonomic* if there exists a number $r$ and rational functions $P_1(n), \ldots, P_r(n)$ such that $a_n = P_1(n) a_{n-1} + \ldots + P_r(n) a_{n-r}$ for $n\geq r$. A number of facts are known (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function)) eg. various closure properties. Is there an algorithm to test whether all elements of a P-recursive sequence are integral (ie. given the initial values $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ and the recusion)?

Comment: It should be hard - I have no answer why in this particular instance, but the following related problem is open:
Given a sequence of complex numbers satisfying a linear recurrence (constant coefficients) of length $n$, and the number of zeros in the sequence is finite. Give a sharp upper bound of the number of zeros the sequence can have as a function of $n$. The best upper bound known is something like $e^{e^{e^n}}$ or similar...